# In python is the .start() command blocking for the time it takes the thread start to complete?

Tags: python, multithreading

Hypothesis:
thread....start()  blocks until start completes.
Question:
Is hypothesis True or False?

[Start http web server then open browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295378/start-http-web-server-then-open-browser) has the following code.

```
import sys
import time
import threading
import webbrowser
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 3600
url = f"http://{ip}:{port}"


def start_server():
    server_address = (ip, port)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()


threading.Thread(target=start_server).start()
webbrowser.open_new(url)

while True: # make a blocker to prevent the application finish of execute:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

This works fine. However, the following also works.

```
import sys
import time
import threading
import webbrowser
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 3600
url = f"http://{ip}:{port}"


def start_server():
    server_address = (ip, port)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()


threading.Thread(target=start_server).start()
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

Hypothesis:
thread....start() actually blocks until start completes. So,`webbrowser.open_new(url)` does not execute until start completes. Thus making the following unnecessary.

```
while True: # make a blocker to prevent the application finish of execute:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

I have not been able to prove or disprove the Hypothesis after extensive searching.

Comment: Remember that, because if the Python GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), only one thread at a time can execute Python code.  When your thread starts, it gets the CPU until the thread blocks for I/O or enters some non-Python code, then the main thread can continue.  There's no guarantee of this, but that's how it works.

Comment: Yeah like Tim said, Python is single-threaded; if you want true parallelism, you'd have to use multiprocessing.

Comment: @TimRoberts althoug only one thread executes at once due to the GIL, the Python runtime can (and will) change the running thread, independent of I/O blocking or running non-Python code: the thread-change can take place at any byte-code instruction boundary on the Python VM.
What gives you deterministic and user-controllable context switches, like you describe, is async based code.

Comment: Folks: an HTTP Server like this is perfectly fine with multi-threading in Python: waiting for an http connection to arrive is I/O blocking, and other threads just run in a transparent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no blocking when calling `Thread.start()` in the way you suggest.
The call is blocking in the sense that a call is placed that initalizes the new-thread internal state, and a system call is made to start the actual OS Thread - but that should take less than 1ms. The function that is the target of the thread is only called on the new thread, and the main thread will continue to run, regardless of what takes place inside that function.

If you want your program not to end, there is no need to resort to a complicated pausing loop like the one you setup - just place a call to `threading.join()` instead. *This* will block until all other threads end running, and only them the threading calling `join()` will proceed.